# How to display Selected option value Selected in option tag in Django Template File?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to keep user selected option active from the long SELECT OPTION dropdown list what they choose from SELECT OPTION. active mean display selected value. Like by default in select options it shows Spanish To English(first one) but if user selects French To English I want to keep selected this one

This is my HTML form in template file.

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="d-flex form-inputs">
<select class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select-lg" name="lang_txt">
<option value="span_to_eng">Spanish To English</option>
<option value="eng_to_span">English To Spanish</option>
<option value="french_to_eng">French To English</option>
</select>
<input name="txt" class="form-control p-3" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<a href="#"><img src="/static/assets/image/search.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
</form>
```

This is views function

```
def lang_convert_view(request):
if request.method == "POST" and 'txt' in request.POST:
    txt = request.POST.get('txt')
    selected_lang = request.POST.get('lang_txt')
    data = custom_function_name(txt)
    context = {'data': data}
else:
    context = {}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: What does active mean?

Comment: Hi @SunderamDubey, active mean display selected value. Like by default  in select options it shows Spanish To English(first one) but if user select French To English I want to keep selected this one

Comment: Well, it is a by default behaviour, what you are talking about and if you have to keep selected any value first time, so you can use `selected` in option tag.

Comment: Sorry! Maybe I was not able to explain the problem clearly. It doesn't matter what option keep selecting in the first time. My concern is I want to keep select option based on user's selection

Comment: Yes, I am also talking about that, it is a default behaviour refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select)

Comment: Hello @Raj are you trying to say you want to keep user selected value as active after submitting form? If yes then easy way is you should try using [`Django Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/) and while rendring you've to pass appropriate object django form file render out all default values selected by perticular user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views:

```
def lang_convert_view(request):
   if request.method == "POST" and 'txt' in request.POST:
       txt = request.POST.get('txt')
       selected_lang = request.POST.get('lang_txt')
       data = custom_function_name(txt)
       context = {'data': data}
   else:
         data = Model.objects.get(id='your query')
         context = {'data': data}
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="d-flex form-inputs">
<select class="form-select" aria-label=".form-select-lg" name="lang_txt">
<option value="span_to_eng" {% if data.selected_lang == 'span_to_eng' %}selected{% endif %}>Spanish To English</option>
<option value="eng_to_span" {% if data.selected_lang == 'eng_to_span' %}selected{% endif %}>English To Spanish</option>
<option value="french_to_eng" {% if data.selected_lang == 'french_to_eng' %}selected{% endif %}>French To English</option>
</select>
<input name="txt" class="form-control p-3" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<a href="#"><img src="/static/assets/image/search.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Ibrahim Khan, Is It data. selected_lang instead data.lang?

Comment: @Raj Yes it is basically the field name from your model: Say you have filed named 'selected_lang' in the model where you are saving the selected lang then yes it's data.selected_lang